# Best approach for my requirements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have tables table 'A' and table ‘B’ table ‘c’
Table A

---

Aid AC1 AC2

---

1   23.34

Table B

---

Bid BC1 BC2

---

1   34.56

Table C

---

Cid CC1 CC2

---

1

AC2 and BC2 are derived values and always changes. 
CC1 is sum (AC1)*AC2 and CC2 = Sum (BC1)*BC2
 In my UI I need show these calculated values from all these tables. If the user likes to save I need to lock the values and save AC2, BC2, CC1, CC2.we are planning to use views for this but views are really slow. What is the alternative approach?

Comment: The alternative approach is to normalize your database.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.  If you are wondering why I mention this, you don't know what it means.

Comment: `but views are really slow` That is completely inaccurate. Views are just queries stored in the database and are run in the very same way as any other query, with the same performance as if it were a normal query. Of course, slow queries (due to poor indexes, incorrect filtering or bad hardware) are going to be canned into equally slow views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use indices, then you will get faster views.
Every column that appears in a *group by* statement, *order by* statement or in a condition makes views faster when indexed.
If you have expressions like:
    select ... 
    where A=...
    group by B
    order by C

Then you'd better make A, B and C indices

Comment: View is so complex on which columns should in create index?